# How can I generate an EAN 13 barcode shorter in length?

Tags: barcode

I generated an EAN 13 barcode by using IDAutomationHC39M font. I found this barcode I generated is so long in width,so each bar is so thin. However, I found somebody's EAN 13 barcode is shorter in length and each bar got more density. How can I achieve the same result? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pictures would help us understand what you are trying to do.

EAN 13 does not use the code 39 symbology, which is what IDAutomationHC39M produces. Instead EAN 13 uses a binary encoding scheme similar to the UPC symbol that encodes a series of bars and spaces that depends on the position in the symbol and the number being represented.

It's one of the more complex symbologies. You can utilize the following code to create your own EAN 13 with client-side JavaScript.

```js
// The MIT License (MIT)

// Copyright (c) 2017, Notionovus, LLC.

// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
// FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
// DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

// Generic arrays for drawing 5-bit graphics. Building blocks for all barcode symbologies
// Painstakingly derived gobblety-goop, but essentially the two middle sections of image data unique to each graphic
var array5bit_A = new Array ( 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/',
 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/',
 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAD/',
 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/',
 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/',
 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/',
 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'SL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+',
 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/',
 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
var array5bit_B = new Array ( 'US0CAuSD38g', 'UUYCA7QBErs', 'ajEDAm49ReY', 'UUoCA+juogg', 'bjEDAjQrOn0', 'bkoDA3iPVH4',
 'ajUDAt82atY', 'UU4CA1nljTg', 'cjEDAghkmFU', 'ckoDA0TA9lY', 'izUEAhrxcbg', 'ck4DAxY8F10', 'bjUDAlvFFR8', 'bk4DAxdhexw',
 'ajkDAr7LFAw', 'UVICAyQ+UJI', 'TTECAq7UnEM', 'TUoCA+Jw8kA', 'ZjUDAmZGozo', 'TU4CA7CME0s', 'ajUDAvnk9E4', 'ak4DA7VAmk0',
 'ZjkDAtle3bI', 'TVICAxOyzrM', 'STUCAqHeHtM', 'SU4CA+16cNA', 'h6QEAZKdo54', 'SVICA62zYxM', 'RTkCAqx1lb4', 'RVICA/z3WM0',
 'QT0CAkdoxRU', 'KFYBA46vJCA');

// Painstakingly derived gobblety-goop, but essentially the front, back and mid-matter common to all barcode images...
var stringStart = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/A';
var stringMid = 'AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
var stringEnd = 'AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="';

function genBarcode(inputString,intWidth,intHeight) { // Input is a long string of 1's and 0's, output is the HTML <img> stack
// Pads to the last character to ensure length is divisible by 5
   var intRawmod = inputString.length % 5; // Modulo 5 remainder
   if (intRawmod > 0) for (var i = 0; i < 5 - intRawmod; i++) inputString += "0"; // If not evenly divisible, pad with zeroes
   var arraySeq = new Array (intChunks = inputString.length / 5); // Create array for as many chunks as are now in input string

   for (var i = 0; i < intChunks; i++) arraySeq[i] = parseInt(inputString.substr(i * 5, 5), 2); // Converts string of 1's and 0's to integer array

// Takes integer array and converts to "<img ...>" graphics for display
   var resultString = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < arraySeq.length; i++) {
    resultString += stringStart + array5bit_A[arraySeq[i]] + stringMid + array5bit_B[arraySeq[i]] + stringEnd + intWidth + '" height="' + intHeight + '">';
   }
   return resultString;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////
// Symbology-specific arrays

// UPC Specific Arrays
var arrayCodeEANBin, arrayStructEAN;
arrayCodeEANBin = [ [ '0001101', '0011001', '0010011', '0111101', '0100011', '0110001', '0101111', '0111011', '0110111', '0001011' ], [ '0100111', '0110011', '0011011', '0100001', '0011101', '0111001', '0000101', '0010001', '0001001', '0010111' ], [ '1110010', '1100110', '1101100', '1000010', '1011100', '1001110', '1010000', '1000100', '1001000', '1110100' ] ];
arrayStructEAN = ['000000', '001011', '001101', '001110', '010011', '011001', '011100', '010101', '010110', '011010'];

///////////////////////////////////////////
// Global Variables
var strRaw = "";
var strText = "";

///////////////////////////////////////////
// Symbology-specific functions
function funcEAN() { // EAN-13
var intSumOdd = 0, intSumEven = 0, intCheck, i, j, strStruct;

// Compute check digit and add it to raw string
 for (i = 0; i < 12; i += 2) {
  intSumEven += parseInt(strText[i]);
  intSumOdd += parseInt(strText[i+1]);
 }
 intCheck = ((intSumOdd * 3) + intSumEven) % 10;
 if (intCheck > 0) {
    intCheck = 10 - intCheck;
 }
 strText += intCheck;

// Converts Code EAN array into string of 1's and 0's
 strRaw = "101";
// First six bar sequences
 strStruct = arrayStructEAN[strText[0]];
 for (i = 1; i < 7; i += 1) {
   strRaw += arrayCodeEANBin[strStruct[i-1]][strText[i]];
 }
// Middle sequence
 strRaw += "01010";
// Last six bar sequences, including check digit
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
  strRaw += arrayCodeEANBin[2][strText[i+7]];
 }
 strRaw += "101";
} // End EAN-13


var buttonBarcode = document.getElementById("btnGenBar");
buttonBarcode.onclick = function () {
 var intHt = intWd = 0;
 var strImages = "";
 document.getElementById("textImages").value = strImages;
 intWd = document.getElementById("textWidth").value;
 intHt = document.getElementById("textHeight").value;
 strText = document.getElementById("textBarcode").value;
 funcEAN();
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = strImages = genBarcode(strRaw,intWd,intHt);
 document.getElementById("textImages").value = strImages;
 document.getElementById("textRaw").value = strRaw;
 document.getElementById("textImages").select();
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>EAN-13 Barcodes in vanilla JavaScript</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
  <h1>EAN-13 Barcodes written in vanilla JavaScript</h1>
  <h4>Enter text (a 12-digit number), enter a non-ridiculous height in pixels, enter a width between 4 (so small) and 40 (gigantor) and press the button. Magic will ensue. Print page or copy HTML out of box and paste it where it will do some good.</h4>  
 <div id="inputForm">
    Enter Text:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textBarcode" placeholder="12 Digit Number" tabindex=1/>
    &nbsp;Height:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textHeight" size="3" placeholder="40-100" maxlength="5" tabindex=2/>
    &nbsp;Width:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="textWidth" size="3" placeholder="4.0-40.9" maxlength="5" tabindex=3/>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="btnGenBar" value="Generate Barcode" tabindex=4/>
 </div>
 <p></p>
 <div id="result"></div>
 <p></p>
 <textarea rows="30" cols="110" id="textImages" tabindex=0></textarea>
 <p></p>
 <textarea rows="3" cols="110" id="textRaw" tabindex=0></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./JS-EAN-13.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you very much for your help! Sorry, I am not IT guy, I do not know the coding. Anyway your help is much appreciated.